# How to combine two streams in RxJs and a bit more?

Tags: rxjs, angular2-forms

I have a reactive form. As I'm typing and stop for 3 secs - it should `console.log(form.value)`. But when I click `submit` — `console.log(form.value)` should be logged immediately and also prevent making previous `console.log()` that was waiting for 3 secs. And after as I'm typing - and not press `submit` - it should `console.log()` after 3 secs again.

I'm pretty newbie to to RxJs. I've just figured out how to make the first part using `debounceTime()` operator. But I cannot wrap my head around how to "inject" submit event into stream of the form and prevent it from `console.log()`;

[Link on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1dugk)

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="name"><br>
  <input type="text" formControlName="age" placeholder="age"><br>

  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name': [],
      'age': []
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(3000)
    ).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

*Expected behavior:*

when I'm typing, stop for 2 secs - nothing happens, if I stop then for 3 secs or more then `console.log(form.value)`;

When press `submit` should `console.log(form.value)` right away and cancel previous waiting of first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gn1dwx

So, thinking in streams, we have:

- a stream of submits
- a stream of debounced change events

We want to avoid duplicate events. So, we merge our 2 streams, and add the distinctUntilChanged operator to avoid duplicate values. We serialize/deserialize since we dont want distinct to operate on instances, but values.

To cleanup our subscription when this component is destroyed, we use takeUntil to automatically close the observable, which automatically will take care of our subscription (always clean up subscriptions!)

Note: changing a value, waiting 4 seconds and then clicking submit will not trigger the subscription. I assume this is intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `unsubscribe` from the Observable when the form is submitted.

[Check it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjbrns?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  form: FormGroup;

  subscription;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'name': [],
      'age': []
    });

    this.subscription = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(3000)
    ).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. But issue with this implementation is that after you clicked Submit - 'auto-save' feature doesn't work anymore. But it still should work after Submit is clicked.